# When API hits successfully I wants to navigate to another page in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

My api response is: when api hits its give status code 200 but i got error unexpected end of json format  and do not navigate to another page in flutter.
My controller

```
static Future<UserLogin> ForgetPassword(String email) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(
          'http://192.168.0.134:8080/AtdochubJ-3/send-otp?email=${email}'),
    );
    print(email);
    print('response++ $response');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return UserLogin.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
     
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load UserLogin');
    }
  }
forget password button code:
Center(
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          final String email = emailController.text;

                          UserLogin res =
                              await LoginController.ForgetPassword(email);
                          print(res);

                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ResetPassword()));
                        },
 child: const Text("Send OTP"),
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 89, 168))),
                      )),
```

Comment: Check your response with Postman, what response do you get?  You may also use https instead of http, try to change it

Comment: @Ozan Taskiran  i check my response the response body is blank because i send request through object and status code 200

Comment: I mean if your response is blank UserLogin.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)); cant work. How should it create a UserLogin object from a blank json :D